# How to analyze complete response of Node-RED HTTP Node

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm trying to migrate a Node-RED flow from a Mac to the IBM cloud. 
Scenario:

1. **HTTP GET Request** directly (alternative **a**: Node-RED installed on Mac) to a local intranet system or (alternative **b**, Node-RED used on IBM Cloud) via Secure Gateway to the same system. In both cases I can see a cut-off XML response in the debug window, so there is data returned (UTF-8).
2. **Transform to Object**: the conversion of that XML data to an object works okay for (**a**) but results in the error "Unclosed root tag" for (**b**).

As the responses are cut-off I can not compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output to the debug tab is deliberately trimmed to stop it overwhelming the websocket connection to the browser with too much data.

If you change the debug node to output to the "debug tab and console" the full message will be output to Node-RED logs and you should be able to compare them.